# 'Filename cannot be empty' appears when use imagecreatefromjpeg() function

Tags: php, thumbnails, php-gd

I have a code to upload an image, then creates thumbnail on the fly for this uploaded image.

**The following code that creates the thumbnail (thumb.php).**

```
$fileName = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'src');
$width = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'width', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$height = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'height', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileName); //<=== the error message indicates to this line
$tmp_im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$imWidth = imagesx($im);
$imHeight = imagesy($im);
imagecopyresampled($tmp_im, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $imWidth, $imHeight);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($tmp_im);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($tmp_im);
```

**The following code that upload the image, then implement the creation of thumbnail for the uploaded image, then display this thumbnail.**

```
require_once ('thumb.php');

$image_dir = "images/";
if($_FILES['photo']['error'] == 0){  
    $fileUPloaded = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $image_dir.$fileUPloaded);
    echo "<a href='".$image_dir.$fileUPloaded."'><img src='thumb.php?src=".$image_dir.$fileUPloaded."&width=350&height=250' alt='' /></a>";
}
```

Now, why appears an error `Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): Filename cannot be empty`.

Note that the image is uploaded, and was created thumbnail for uploaded image, and was displayed thumbnail. so, why that error message appear ?

Comment: If you do `var_dump($filename)` does a file by that name actually exist? Do you have the path information you need as part of the name? Also what are you getting out of doing filter_input without specifying a filter? I would say you want to be very careful about any file name of a file you have uploaded.

Comment: @Elin: Thanks, no, gives me `null` value, but how `null` and it doing everything ?. regarding filter_input I have put just an example not the final code. –  Lion King 1 min ago   edit

Comment: No one can tell you what is wrong with your code if you are not showing your code.   If you are getting a null that's obviously the problem, just exactly as the error message said.  Figure out why that is.  What happens when you dump echo INPUT_GET?

Comment: @Elin: gives me `int 1`.

Comment: Try `var_dump(isset($_GET['src']);`

Comment: @Elin: gives me `boolean false`.

Comment: Well that's the problem then, you need to make sure that you have src.

Comment: @Elin: [**Thank you**]. I have been solved the problem. you must first check if the `$_GET['src']` has a value or no, and thus, I have used `isset()` function to check if there is a value or no. that's it.